# Kiel nomiĝas la supera parto de la unua paĝo de gazetoj?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Saluton, kiel nomiĝas la super parto de la unua paĝo de gazetoj, kiu enhavas titolon, daton, ktp. Mi trovis, ke tiu nomiĝas "manchette" en la franca, kaj "masthead" aŭ "nameplate" en la angla. Sed mi ne trovis esperantan nomon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi sugestas *ĵurnalkapo* kiel tradukon. En la esperanta `kapo` rilatas pintan parton (aŭ supran kiam oni konsideras normalan pozicion): pafilkapo, pinglokapo, martelkapo, ktp.

En almenaŭ du aliaj kunmetemaj lingvoj oni trovas tian tradukon: en la skribita ĉina [报头](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8A%A5%E5%A4%B4) (laŭsigne ĵurnalo-kapo) kaj en la germana [Zeitungskopf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitungskopf) (kapo de ĵurnalo).

Answer (score 1):

Saluton!

Nu, varianto el la franca devenas de parto de vesto - "manumo".

Varianto "masthead" (https://www.etymonline.com/word/mast-head) estas "kapo de masto", devenas el mara/ŝipa terminaro. En esperanto ni preferas vorton "pinto" anstataŭ "kapo". Ĉu iu gazeto aŭ revuo havas maston - mi dubas.

Varianto "nameplate" estas "plako/plato de/por nomo".

Do, ĉiuj varintoj estas nur kutimo/moro de iu popolo. Ni povas konstrui bezonatan vorton rekte el la senco, kiun vi volas esprimi.

Diversaj lokoj ĉe gazeto: linio, kolumno, paĝo, artikolo, kampo aŭ loko (mem).

Tie povas esti: nomo (de gazeto), titolo (de artikolo), dato kaj numero, devizo aŭ slogano k.t.p.

Ĉio povas havi ecojn: ĉefa, aŭtora, redaktora, alvoka, informa, anonca k.t.p.

Iam ie povas esti iu konstanta sinprezenta bildo - taŭgas vortoj blazono aŭ logotipo. Kaj kiel formo - ŝildo aŭ ŝildeto...

Do, ni povas konstrui:

nomlinio, nomloko, titollinio, titolloko, titolpaĝo, numerlinio, numerloko, datlinio, datloko, divizlinio, divizloko, ĉefpaĝo, ĉefkolumno, ĉefartikolo, aŭtorpaĝo, aŭtorkolumno, aŭtorartikolo, reaktorartikolo, anonclinio, anoncloko, anonckolumno, anoncpaĝo, blazonloko k.t.p. k.t.p.

Se vi uzos iun el tiuj vortoj - mi vin komprenos certe kaj ĝuste, eĉ senrigarde al vortaroj kaj kutimoj en mi propra denaska lingvo.

Povas esti kurioze, sed iu esprimo "mi vidas la nomlinion, datlinion, blazonlokon kaj divizkampon..." en iun lingvon povas esti tradukita kiel "I see masthead, nameplate, nameplate and nameplate..." aŭ iel simile. Do, grado de via precizeco dependas nur de vi.

Sed alia flanko de monero de precizeco estas enueco.